# Custom Vim command to open file based on the day

Tags: vim

I am trying to streamline my process and automatically open or create a file based on the date. I go to this file a bunch over the day. Before I was using the below command, then I would have to navigate to the file, or create it for that day.

`map <Leader>gn :e ~/Dropbox/notes<cr>`

I am playing with something like this. And it works, the only problem is it does not open the file, I have to hit `,gt` then `enter`. The above command will open the folder without hitting enter.

`map <Leader>gt :e ~/Dropbox/notes/journal/<C-r>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d") . '.md'<cr>`

Comment: Silly answer, but can't you just add another <cr> to the end of the mapping? Works for me. Adding `G` would put you at the end of the file regardless...

Comment: Haha, that was it. Thanks @moopet, If you want to submit a answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time Vim is waiting for an `Enter` in a mapping, you can just add another `<cr>`.

If the file already exists, this will move the cursor down a line, so to keep things consistent, let's add a `G` to take you to the bottom of the file (it's a journal, after all). Change it to:

```
map <Leader>gt :e ~/Dropbox/notes/journal/<C-r>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d") . '.md'<cr><cr>G
```

Comment: I would recommend using `nnoremap` instead of just plain `map`

Answer (score 0):

Vimscript is evaluated exactly like the Ex commands typed in the `:` command-line. There were no variables in `ex`, so there's no way to specify them. When typing a command interactively, you'd probably use `<C-R>=` to insert variable contents:

```
:sleep <C-R>=timetowait<CR>m<CR>
```

... but in a script, `:execute` must be used. It's usually more readable in mappings, too. (That's why I'm adding this to the accepted answer.) All the literal parts of the Ex command must be quoted (single or double quotes), and then concatenated with the variables:

```
execute 'sleep' timetowait . 'm'
```

#### Your example

```
map <Leader>gt :execute 'e ~/Dropbox/notes/journal/' . strftime("%Y-%m-%d") . '.md'<cr>G
```

Variant with `printf()` (more readable when there are many identifiers:

```
map <Leader>gt :execute printf('e ~/Dropbox/notes/journal/%s.md', strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))<cr>G
```

Another alternative would be a `:help map-expr`:

```
map <expr> <Leader>gt printf(":e ~/Dropbox/notes/journal/%s.md\<CR>G", strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

#### Additional critique

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- Also, this mostly only makes sense from *normal mode*, so `:nnoremap` would be ideal.